# How do I Select and change multiple records

Tags: database, forms, database-design

I currently have a Tabular Form that gets its data from a Query that shows all records with the "Status" "Repair Complete".

The headings are

Device
Serial Number
Despatch to
Despatch Date
Despatch with
Tracking Number
Despatched by
Status

I want to scan (hand held scanner) Multiple devices then click an update button in the form header. Update

Despatch to
Despatch Date
Despatch with
Tracking Number
Despatched by

with new information and then change the status from "Repair Complete" to "Despatched"

Is this possible first of all and if so please can you give me some guidance on how to do it. If you can think of any other ways then please let me know.

Cheers

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using two tables and relating them.
1.Table one would basically be the serial number of the product as a attribute(column) and Status as the other attribute.
2.Table two would be your detailed table of dispatch,which would have again your serial number,probably a dispatchID and all the other attributes.
Use SerialNumber as a Foreign Key(Reference it).

For updation,you could use two update operations.
1.
    `Update TABLENAME
    set            Despatchto="value",Despatchdate="value",Despatchwith="value",TrackingNumber="value",Despatched    by="value"
    where
    SerialNumber="value";`

2.
    `Update TABLENAME2
    set Status="Despatched"
    where SerialNumber="value";`

Comment: Cheers, I will give it a go a little later and let you know how I gewt on with it.